# Calling Javascript from a HTML webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, trello

I understand that the title is a little difficult to understand basically there is javascript code within this html page (https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=1105ed3bc15daddc1cc2dae6edd5bae3). What I need to do is call it using javascript code.

As I'm relatively new to javascript I have no idea how to do this.

Whilst im on the topic of Trello, using this code and (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js) can you possible help us to create a set of functions in javascript to add a new card to Trello, we're having authorization issues.

My main question is the first part, but if you can answer both that'd be great.

Comment: So you need to be able to call this to an HTML page?

Comment: Make the stuff in the js file a function, in the HTML file refer to it as an external js file. Then call that function.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function foo(data)
{
    // do stuff with JSON
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=1105ed3bc15daddc1cc2dae6edd5bae3?callback=foo';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right you could try [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)
or

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'pathToScript';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
```

Comment: Just to clarify that i replace the 'pathToScript' with the url?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to include that js file as a external file like:

```
<script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=1105ed3bc15daddc1cc2dae6edd5bae3"></script>
```

So you will be able to call any function from that html page.

Comment: But how would i do that if im going to be importing a javascript file into CRM, I dont think HTML will work.

Comment: I dont understand about CRM. But if you have a HTML page and you need to call a function from a external javascript file. you can do so by just including that external file like I mentioned above in your HTML page.